# JSON: help with looping through array with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

Hi I'm having trouble with an array I get via ajax post. My return on success looks like this:

```
["OptimiseWeb","Photos","Portal","Projects","Public"]
```

My problem is that when I do an alert(this) foreach item in the array instead of getting the directory ie. Photos. It's treating it as a string and is looping through each character.

Here is my code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>filesystem/get_dropbox_directories", 
    data: dataString,
    dataType: JSON,
    success: function(arr)
    {
        alert(arr);
        $.each(arr, function() {
            alert(this);
            var opt = $('<option />'); 
            opt.val(this);
            opt.text(this);
            $('#dropbox-directories').append(opt); 

        });


        $('.drop-account-indicator').css('display', 'none');
    }
});
```

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong? Here is my PHP if it helps?

```
$data = array();

        foreach($contents as $sub){

            if($sub->is_dir){
                $data[] = str_replace('\/', '', $sub->path);
            }

        }

        header('Content-type: application/json');
        echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: btw this is not required: <?php echo base_url(); ?> a relative url should be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON` should be `"json"`:

```
dataType: "json",
```

`dataType` should be a string. `JSON` passes a global object, while `"json"` passes a string (jQuery doesn't know what to do with `JSON`, but with `"json"` it will parse the response).

[`jQuery.ajax` docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick answer. And it worked thanks! Stupid mistake :(

Comment: The JSON should hv thrown a js error and the ajax call shouldnt have gone through.. nt sure if this is his prob.. may be he has a variable names JSON.. @iamjonesy did this fix your problem?

Comment: @zzzz `JSON` is included as an object in some browsers. It's a JSON parsing library.

Comment: Didn't get any JS errors. Tried debugging through chrome and FF consoles and no error